# Is there exist $n_p\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $p+1\equiv 0 \mod (4n_p-p)$ for prime $p(\ge 5)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I am looking a proof for,

> Existence of a positive integer $n_p$ such that $$p+1\equiv 0 \mod (4n_p-p) $$ for each prime $p\ge 5.$

But I have no idea to get an attempt to this problem in general.
I tried small numerical values of $p$ and it seems like this result hold for large primes also.
Any help would be appreciate. Thank You.

Comment: Also is requires that $4n_p-p\gt 0.$

Comment: For $p\equiv 3 mod 4$,it's trivial.For $p\equiv 1mod 4$,it's equal to say that $p+1$has a factor congruent to $3 mod 4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the prime $337$? 
$338=2*13^2$ has no prime factors that is congruent to $3 (mod4)$